# Why isn't my carousel working?

Tags: featured-product

I am using this carousel...

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all-category-product-carousel.html

My home pages is here... www.indigomeadowscrafting.com

I can't for the life of me figure out why it is in a vertical row instead of horizontal.

Any clues?

FYI: I did email the developer but wanted to see if anyone here knew anything!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an external extension and not about Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Jquery and CSS of Carousel is not included.

Please place the file `jcarousel.responsive.css` in `skin/frontend/YOURTHEME/pcarousel/css` and `jcarousel.responsive.js` , `jquery.jcarousel.min.js` in 'skin/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/pcarousel/js/'

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you so it might be useful for future user

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing all of the pcarousel javascript files.

Please check the directory `skin/frontend/default/default/` for a directory called `pcarousel`. Move this directory either to `skin/frontend/base/default/` or your templates skin directory.